# Can Yum express a preference for x86_64 over i386 packages?

Tags: linux, centos, yum, 64bit

I run a 64-bit version of CentOS5. At the moment, when I run Yum updates or installs, unless Yum is purged of i386 packages prior, it will install i386 packages when x86_64 are available.

Is it possible for Yum to install x86_64 packages as first preference and then if no 64-bit packages are available, install i386 packages instead?

I know that I can set preferences so that *only* 64-bit packages are installed, but I don't want to do this, as it prevents 32-bit packages from being installed if they're the only option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set `multilib_policy=best` in your yum.conf, it defaults to 'all' so it installs both i386 and x86_64 packages. When you set it to 'best' it will only install i386 if there is no x86_64 version.

From the CentOS 5 yum.conf man page:

```
multilib_policy - Can be set to ’all’ or ’best’. All means
install all possible arches for any package you  want  to
install.  Therefore yum install foo will install foo.i386
and foo.x86_64 on x86_64, if it is available. Best  means
install the best arch for this platform, only.
```

Comment: Ahh, okay. That sounds like the answer I'm looking for, thanks! I'd vote it up, but I don't have enough points.